# Computed Setter as validator

Tags: validation, vue.js, computed-properties, element-ui

I'm trying to use a computed property to monitor the value in `ElementUI`'s `el-input` component, but the value I want is not being displayed in the component. Specifically, when the user types an input, I want to limit the length to three characters without having the input show more. For example, I don't want behavior where the user types 5 characters, and then when the `el-input` is not in focus, the value gets corrected. I realize that there is a `maxlength` attribute, but I want to make the validation more general. As an extension to this, I want to be able to call any kind of function on the content of the `el-input` and show the result of that function. This is what I'm doing right now:

template:

```
    <el-input
        :placeholder="placeholder"
        :value="inputValue"
        @keypress.enter.native="$emit('keypress-enter',event)"
        @input="input"
        :disabled="disabled"
        :autosize="true"
        :readonly="readonly"
        :type="inputType"
        :rows="rows"
        v-model="inputValue"
        > 
    </el-input>
```

script:

```
computed: {
    inputValue: {
        get: function(){
            return this.temp;
            // This is what I eventually want to do
            // return this.validationFunction.f(this.temp);
        },
        set: function(newVal) {
            // This is what I'm doing right now to test
            this.temp = "";
            this.temp = (newVal.length > 3) ? newVal.slice(0,3) : newVal;
        }
    },
},
data: {
    return {
        temp: ""
    }
}
```

What is the best way to get the desired behavior?

Comment: This is just fine! Closing it as opinion based. But there's unnecessary use of `this.temp="";`

Comment: The thing is, the value of the input isn't getting validated at all. I can still put in any number of characters without the input being limited

Comment: oh, then it's not a setter problem. you should validating through input event.

Comment: Validate in the `setter` not the `getter`. The getter should only ever return the value, not logic against the value.

Answer (score 2):

The setter is working but the `el-input` doesn't know it. The problem is that when the value of `inputValue` stops changing, Vue figures it doesn't need to notify anybody.

So you have to change the value, then in `$nextTick` change it to what you want it to be. That way the notifications always happen. There is, unfortunately, no way I know of to simply tell Vue to send notifications about a computed or data item.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    temp: 'a'
  },
  computed: {
    inputValue: {
      get() {
        return this.temp;
      },
      set(newValue) {
        this.temp = newValue;
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.temp = newValue.substr(0, 3);
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <el-input v-model="inputValue"></el-input>
  Actual value: {{ temp }}
</div>
```